# QML does not center the component

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

I have a simple component which is designed to show an image with some text under it as follows:

```
Rectangle{
    id: functionView

    RowLayout {
        spacing: 350
        anchors.centerIn: parent

        Item {
            Image {
                id: upload_pic
                source: "http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/custom-icon-design/mono-general-4/128/upload-icon.png"
                Text {
                    text: "Upload Images"
                    anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
                    anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
                    anchors.bottomMargin: -20
                }
            }
            Layout.fillWidth: true
        }

        Item {
            Image {
                id: workflow_pic
                source: "http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/icons8/windows-8/128/Data-Workflow-icon.png"
                Text {
                    text: "Upload Workflow"
                    anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
                    anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
                    anchors.bottomMargin: -20
                }
            }
            Layout.fillWidth: true
        }


    }
}
```

However, this is not aligned (either vertically or horizontally) on the component window. This can be verified using `qmlscene`. The images are directly linked in the component source.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to center your `RowLayout` in its parent, which is a `Rectangle` that doesn't have its `width` property set.
Set the rectangle's width to some value or to its parent width for example by `width: parent.width` or by setting its anchors like for example:

```
anchors.left: parent.left
anchors.right: parent.right
```

Comment: You need to do the same for the height. Set the Rectangles' `anchors.fill: parent`